# Multiple developers on one git repository

Tags: git, github, sourcecontrol

I have a git repository with code from salesforce instance.
The SF project is managed in eclipse (keppler version with egit plugin). I ignored the package and schema files in order to prevent conflicts.
I would like to have another developer using the same instance and repository with his own Salesforce and git credentials.
What are the steps that i need to perform in order to get the new developer start working with the git repository?

Here is what i tried on the 2nd developer computer:
1. Created a new SF project and didn't get the components from SF (In order to get them from the repository).
2. Shared the project, choose git and created a new local repository.
3. Setup remote repository with the path of the repository and the 2nd developer user name and pass.
4. When i'm asked to set the directory and choose the directory of the local repository, i get a notification that the directory is not empty.

That's as far as i got...i tried additional ways to set it up but none of them worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Dagish. It's not entirely clear whether your question is specific to the salesforce aspects or to git and github in general. General questions on git(hub) are not really on topic here, you would probably get more and faster answers at stackoverflow.

Comment: Samuel - The question is specific to salesforce. I would like to know what are the steps i need to take regarding salesforce project. Should i get the project from salesforce first? Should i get components from salesforce when i create the project or should i get it from git repository? etc...

Comment: Martin - I saw this post. I understand the flow in general but i would like to know how to set it up for the first time, as i wrote in my comment to Samuel.

Comment: Dagish, maybe it is better to edit your question to be about a very specific aspect. Else it is very broad and rather impossible to answer or not be seen as a duplicate of Martin's question.

Comment: Samuel, I edit the question, hope it will make my question more clear. If you have any additional comments please let me know. Thanks :)